# Difference between Docker from DockerProvider and DockerMsftProvider

Tags: windows, docker, server

What is the difference between two methods to enable containers on Windows Server 2016. I found two sets of commands to do that. One using DockerProvider, and the other - DockerMsftProvider. First is from Docker Doc site, second - from Microsoft site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are basically equivalent, with the exception that DockerProvider can also install pre-release builds.

Docker and Microsoft have WiP to standardize on DockerMsftProvider for production builds, and DockerProvider (likely to be renamed) for pre-release builds.

So for now:

Production: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

Pre-release: https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/docker-windows-server-1709/

The respective doc pages will be adjusted to match.

Comment: Since I stumbled across it, I'll note that the above doc-update plan was being tracked at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/663 but hasn't moved since 2018.

Answer (score 2):

[DockerMSFTProvider](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DockerMsftProvider) looks active as of February 3rd, 2021, its [index](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=825636&clcid=0x409)'s latest version is *19.03.14* from 21st December 2020, slightly behind the [19.03.15 release](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/19.03/#190315) made two days ago.

I was hoping to see a 20.10.x release on DockerMSFTProvider by now, but I guess they're not *yet* ready to ship them.

It looks like [DockerProvider](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DockerProvider) has stopped updates: the latest version in [its index](https://download.docker.com/components/engine/windows-server/index.json) is *19.03.8-beta3* from 2nd April 2020.

I've raised [a ticket](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41608) to discover the fate and future of the DockerProvider as a source of pre-release builds.

Comment: It's there now: `version "20.10.4"`